# Understanding the Intersection of "Advances in Financial Machine Learning" and "Asset Pricing in Stock Market Prediction"

Tags: time-series, asset-pricing, machine-learning

I have been reading "Advances in Financial Machine Learning" by Marcos Lopez de Prado and "Machine Learning in Asset Pricing" by Stefan Nagel, and I noticed that there seems to be little overlap or intersection between the two fields. This has left me confused, and I would like to understand the reasons behind this.

From my understanding, Marcos Lopez de Prado approaches stock trend prediction from a time series analysis perspective. Is this correct? Does this mean that for N stocks, we need N models to learn from? Is this strategy essentially a timing strategy?

On the other hand, cross-sectional research is a stock-picking strategy, right? If we sort the results of the timing models for N stocks at a given time point and pick the top k, is this another stock-picking strategy? How does this compare to cross-sectional stock-picking strategies in terms of superiority or inferiority?

Comment: To me "asset pricing" is the academic discipline that investigates how securities ought to be be priced. It tries to replace the failed CAPM model (that what matters is Beta) with better theories of security pricing. It is an open research area and it is not clear how its findings would be used in practical investing. (Factor investing is one practical offshoot of the Asset Pricing literature, but what the application of ML will lead to, I don't know yet.)